# mod-security: warning, not blocking

Tags: tomcat7, mod-security

I've installed mod-security and can see from the logs that it is warning me in the case of an SQLi attempt. The attempt succeeds however, when I expect it to be prevented. Clearly I'm missing some very obvious setting, but I can't find it!

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set

```
SecRuleEngine On
```

in "modsecurity.conf"? The default is

```
SecRuleEngine DetectionOnly
```

Also see https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#SecRuleEngine

Comment: A simple misconfiguration! :)